# stack 2d density maps along the z axis direction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to do it using contourf, which has an option `contourf(X,Y,Z,...,offset=?,zdir="z")`, see attached figure for illustration.

I tried to do something similar for pcolor but couldn't seem to find similar option. My question is is matplotlib capable of stacking 2d density maps? If so, how?

[image: stacking 2d contourf plots along z axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `pcolor` or `pcolormesh`, you can do this with [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface.html) where you set the Z-value to be constant for a given level (this is done by multiplying the Z-axis value by a matrix of ones) and then use the `facecolors` `kwarg` to create the image.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
x = np.linspace(-5,5,N)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,N)
levels = np.arange(1,10,2)
c_func = lambda n: np.exp(-(x[:,None]**2/n + y[None,:]**2/n))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"))
for level in levels:
    C = c_func(level)
    ax.plot_surface(x[:,None], y[None,:], level*np.ones((N,N)), 
                    facecolors=plt.cm.hot(C))
fig.show()
```

[image]